# Wordpress Manage Categories

Tags: wordpress

I have wp 3.7 +  woocommerce

Creating categories of products, I have noticed that categories are not automatically inserted in the navigation menu. 
Currently I have to do this manually from Appearance -> Menu. 
From the left column i open the menu "product categories", I select the category just created and click 
on "add to menu". Then I have to drag it under "products"

I need that, created a new category of product, to be automatically added to the menu item "Products". Is it possible? Is there any plugin or setting?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing the below plugin. This might solve your problem.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-easy-menu/